# Polynomial function in several variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I would like to prove the following statement :

Let $k$ a field, and $a_1,\cdots ,a_n\in k$. We note $A=k[X_1,\cdots ,X_n]$ the polynomial ring in $n$ variables over $k$.

> If $$ \Psi : \begin{array}{ccc}
> A & \longrightarrow & k \\ 
> f & \longmapsto & f(a_1,\cdots , a_n)
> \end{array}$$
>   then
>   $$\ker \Psi \subset ~<X_1-a_1,\cdots , X_n-a_n >.$$

**1) My first attempt :**

Let $f\in\ker\Psi$, we consider $f$ as an element of $k[X_1,\cdots ,X_{n-1}][X_n]$ and we divise $f$ by $X_n-a_n$, we get
$$f(X_1,\cdots ,X_n)=Q_n(X_1,\cdots ,X_n)(X_n-a_n) +R_n(X_1,\cdots ,X_n).$$
We do it again with by remplacing $f$ by $R_1$ see as an element of $k[X_1,\cdots , X_{n-2},X_n][X_{n-1}]$. By doing this $n$ times we obtain
$$f(X_1,\cdots ,X_n)=Q_n(X_1,\cdots ,X_n)(X_n-a_n)+\cdots +Q_1(X_1,\cdots ,X_n)(X_1-a_n)+R_1(X_1,\cdots ,X_n).$$
Furthermore $f\in\ker\Psi$ so $R_1(a_1,\cdots ,a_n)=0$.

**My problem :**

- I don't know how to continu. If $k[X_1,\cdots,X_n][Y]$ were an Euclidean ring, by using Euclidean division we could use that $\deg_{X_i} (R_i)=0$, so at the end $R_1\in k$, and it follows that $R_1=0$. But $k[X_1,\cdots,X_n][Y]$ isn't an Euclidean ring..

---

**2) My second attempt :**

This method is more direct but use a Taylor formula which I'm not used to use with formal variables. It consist in, using Taylor formula

$$f(X_1,\cdots ,X_n)=f(a_1,\cdots ,a_n) +\sum_{k_1,\cdots, k_n\in U}\dfrac{\partial^{k_1+\cdots +k_n}f}{\partial X_1^{k_1}\cdots\partial X_n^{k_n}}(0,\cdots ,0)(X_1-a_1)^{k_1}\cdots (X_n-a_n)^{k_n}.$$
And use the fact that $f(a_1,\cdots ,a_n)=0$.

**My problems :**

- First, is this proof correct ?
- Do I need to assume that the characteristic of $k$ is different from $0$ ?

---

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In your first attempt, first equation, what can you say about the $X_n$ degree of $R_n$?

Comment: @Mohan , just about nothing since the ring isn't Euclidian. (I think)

Comment: Division algorithm says, if $f$ is a monic polynomial in $t$ (over any commutative ring with 1) and $g$ is any other polynomial, we can divide and get an equation $g=qf+r$ where $\deg r<\deg t$.

Comment: Ok, thanks I didn't know that. So that finishes the proof of my first attempt.